# How to delete all files without deleting a specific file in Asp.net solution explorer's folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying this piece of code to delete all files except a particular file whose path+name is hold by a ViewState.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Projects\BlockSchemeManagement\Attachment");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
         File.Delete(filePath);
```

This code should delete all files but it is not deleting any of them.

This is the viewState to keep this particular file by the way:

```
ViewState["file"] = @parentDir + filename;
```

Can any one give suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Where would you like to delete the files, on the server or on the cliënt?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: i need it for Server side...

Comment: Can you confirm that you're arrray contains entries?

Comment: Check your event log for errors. Your user which is running under IIS needs to have read/write permissions for that folder.

Comment: Make sure the ASP user has permissions to this folder. By default this user is not given access to much of the harddrive..

Comment: @ricky this is the error that i am getting

"The process cannot access the file 'E:\Projects\BlockSchemeManagement\Attachment\06 06 2014 4 40 55 PM.xls' because it is being used by another process".

Comment: I guess ur document is opend somewhere

Comment: The error that you are getting is self explanatory.

Comment: This is not opened anywhere. i can't see it is opened.

Comment: Does your project uses this file? Like creating or opening it...

Comment: Ya for creating & opening both ...

Comment: Just one point, since the windows file system is not case sensitive, you should use string.Equals to perform a case insensitive comparison of file name. Invariably it will bite you.

Answer (score 3):

If file is opened and locked by your application or by any other application then you cannot delete it. Try to ignore the exception on first file and delete other files.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Projects\BlockSchemeManagement\Attachment");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths) 
{
    if (filePath != ViewState["file"])
    {
        try
        {
             File.Delete(filePath);
        } 
          catch { }
    }
}
```

Note that ViewState["file"] should have full name of file such as

E:\Projects\BlockSchemeManagement\Attachment\filename.ext

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the path exists or not as below code as well as the file whichs you want to delete should not be opened anywhere.

```
if (IO.File.Exists(filePaths )) 
{
       foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
       {
           File.Delete(filePath);
       }
}
```

and for your

> How to delete all files without deleting a specific file

question try below code :-

```
 foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
 {   
    var name = new FileInfo(filePath).Name;
   if (filePath != ViewState["file"])
   {
      try
      {
         File.Delete(filePath);
      } 
      catch { }
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use string.Equals to do a case-insensitive comparison on the file name.

Comment: You need to pass one of the StringComparison enumerations to ignore the case.

Comment: im not getting you @ChrisTaylor

Comment: Read the documentation on String.Equals. The new change you did to use ToLower is not frat, you are creating temporary strings which ultimately need to be garbage collected, maybe not a big issue in this case, but since .net offers a better solution that does not have this problem, why not use it. String.Equals(name, ViewState["file"], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the object which is creating and opening this file. You need to dispose that object before deleting the file. Otherwise the handle of that file will be hold by that object. Hence, access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

```
     string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Software Developing\project and project data\LilacInsights\LilacInsights\Pdf\");

            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
if(filePath != "yourfilename with path")
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);

this code run properly , its deleting each file from folder, 

now if u wan to exclude any file from delete jus keep tht file in if condition 
if ()
```